# Measuring the r2_score in a non-linear regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning

I want to measure the r2_score in the kc_house_data data available in kaggle but I connot understand why it gives me a negative result.Can you explain me please?

```
df["combined"] = bedrooms_norm + bathrooms_norm + sqftliving_norm + sqftabove_norm + long_norm + lat_norm + sqftliving15_norm +yrbuilt_norm + grade_norm + floors_norm + sqftbasement_norm+condition_norm
cdf = df[["combined", "price"]]

def log(a, Beta_1, Beta_2, Beta_3):
    y = (Beta_1 * (np.power(Beta_2, a)) + Beta_3)
    return y
beta_3 = 0.10
beta_2 = 1.5
beta_1 = 1
x_data, y_data = (df["combined"].values, df["price"].values)
x_data_norm = x_data / max(x_data)
y_data_norm = y_data / max(y_data)
y_pred = log(x_data_norm, beta_1, beta_2, beta_3)
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(log, x_data_norm, y_data_norm)
x = np.linspace(4, 12, 21613)
x = x / max(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
y = log(x, *popt)
plt.plot(x_data_norm, y_data_norm, 'ro', label='data')
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=3.0, label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('price')
plt.xlabel('combined')
plt.show()

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print("R2-score: %.2f" % r2_score(y_data_norm , y))
```

I tried to use r2_score in sklearn.metrics and I expected a number between 0 to 1 but I don't understand why it calculates a negative number

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print("R2-score: %.2f" % r2_score(y_data_norm , y))
R2-score: -59.51
```

Answer (score 0):

R2 can be negative. As explained in [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score):

> Best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected (average) value of y, disregarding the input features, would get an R2 score of 0.0.

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12991/406174) from CrossValidated explains it really well.